# Get specific object from JSONPath array result after predicate is applied

Tags: arrays, jsonpath

In JSONPath 0.9.1 the following Json path was valid:

http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/?path=$.store.book[?(@.author==%27Nigel%20Rees%27)][0]

returning

```
{
  "category" : "reference",
  "author" : "Nigel Rees",
  "title" : "Sayings of the Century",
  "price" : 8.95
}
```

I've upgraded to the latest one (2.3) and the query now returns empty array.

Is this a bug or the way to retrieve an element from the resulting array has changed?

Answer (score 3):

Given this document:

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

Using JsonPath 2.3.0, the following code returns a `JSONArray` (rather than an `Object[]`):

```
JsonPath.parse(JSON).read("$.store.book[?(@.author==\"Nigel Rees\")]");
```

So, the following code ...

```
JSONArray read = JsonPath.parse(JSON).read("$.store.book[?(@.author==\"Nigel Rees\")]");
System.out.println(read.get(0));
```

... will print:

```
{category=reference, author=Nigel Rees, title=Sayings of the Century, price=8.95}
```

Comment: So I guess this is a feature rather than a bug? I preferred the flexibility of the old version, where you could extract the json object and avoid dealing with arrays in code.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the extracted 'json object' it might  still be possible to avoid dealing with arrays by, for example, using the JsonPath `Filter` feature to create more fine grained predicates?