# extracting single element from jsonpath array after query

Tags: java, jsonpath

I am trying to extract a value from a json string using json-path.
I suspected that my question is related to [Get specific object from JSONPath array result after predicate is applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572081/get-specific-object-from-jsonpath-array-result-after-predicate-is-applied) but the link didn't provide me with the answer. My jsonfile looks like this:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "errorKey": null,
  "results": {
    "payments": [
      {
        "name": "current",
        "all": {
          "revenue": 390.32,
          "count": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "sameYesterday",
        "all": {
          "revenue": 613.24,
          "count": 4
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "yesterday",
        "all": {
          "revenue": 613.24,
          "count": 3
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to get yesterday's payment count. Following query definitely works, but it relies on the position of elements within the json array, which can change:

```
ReadContext ctx = JsonPath.parse(content);
ctx.read("$.results.payments[2].all.count");
```

I was trying to work with name matching:

```
ctx.read("$.results.payments[?(@.name=='yesterday')].all.count[0]")
```

My problem is that this always returns an empty array. ctx.read("$.results.payments[?(@.name=='yesterday')].all.count" returns [3] (logically) and I assumed taking the first element from the result array would be sufficient, but my result array is always empty.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`count` property itself is not an array in your JSON so array notation on `count` such as `count[0]` doesn't work. But the expression `$.results.payments[?(@.name == 'yesterday')].all.count` when evaluated returns a Java list so to get the first `count` we can just get the first element from the list:

```
List<Integer> yesterdayCounts = ctx.read("$.results.payments[?(@.name == 'yesterday')].all.count");
int firstCount = yesterdayCounts.get(0);

assertThat(firstCount).isEqualTo(3);
```

Comment: Hi Marimuthu, my problem is that I want to allow the user to specify a jsonpath to a value in a json object with an url, which i then can use in my dashboarding tool (example: http://burgershop-control.demo.moskito.org/control/main). Therefore I would like to avoid making java level manipulations with the values.